# SQL for adding another column showing Nth occurrence of unique ID within data-set

Tags: sql, csv, amazon-athena

I have a table of patient visits, where each row is a visit. There is a column with the unique patient ID to signify which client the visit was for. I would like to add another column which shows the Nth occurrence of that patient ID within the data-set. So first visit would show 1, second visit shows 2 and so on. I tried searching for similar questions but have not found anything yet, your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide table definitions, sample input data and expected output. Do you *really* want to store this in the table, what happens if someone deletes a row, you will have to recalculate. Best to calculate it when you need it `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY Date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the values using `row_number()`:

```
select v.*,
       row_number() over (partition by patient_id order by visit_date) as seqnum
from visits v;
```

This is called a *window function* (or more specifically a *ranking function*).  It enumerates the rows without gaps starting at `1` for each "partition" (i.e. each `patient_id`).  The `order by` specifies the ordering.

Comment: Unless there is some Athena-specific documentation covering this, https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/window.html may be helpful.